# Repeated Measures Anova in R (Mixed Model?)

Tags: r

I have a data set that I am trying to analyze across both JMP and R that contains 4 columns and 468 rows.

```
    ID     Treatment    Time     Response
H1                 T      10             28
H1                 T      20             0
H1                 T      30             0
H1                 T      40             0
H1                 Y      10             12
H1                 Y      20             5
H1                 Y      30             24
H1                 Y      40             28
H2                 T      10             4
H2                 T      20             12
H2                 T      30             4
H2                 T      40             0
H2                 Y      10             44
H2                 Y      20             12
H2                 Y      30             23
H2                 Y      40             11
```

My full data set contains 13 subjects (represented by ID) each that receive two treatments and are measured 18 times. I am trying to figure out the best way to run a repeated measures analysis on this data.

I was using the formula `am1 <- aov(Response ~ Treatment + (ID/Time), data = df)` but my degrees of freedom appeared off to my colleague so I ask your help on the best approach to go about this problem. I have my data set up for a univariate approach I believe but any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is balanced, you can specify an `Error` term in your formula, here is the example from ?aov:

```
 npk.aovE <- aov(yield ~  N*P*K + Error(block), npk)
```